# Rails jbuilder remove header

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I'm adding jbuilder to a Rails app -- great tool!

I'm getting the list of records I want, but it has extra output I don't want.

This is the jbuilder code:

```
json.locations @locations do |location|
 json.id location.id
 json.name location.name
end
```

The output is:

```
{
  - locations: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Name 2"
    },
```

What I need is:

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Name 2"
    },
```

How can I remove the { - locations:

???

Thanks!!

UPDATE:

I'm hoping there is a line of code for jbuilder that would exclude the root.

Comment: I needed to exclude a root element when returning object

   `@foo = { bar: true, dry: false }
   json.foo @foo `

would print `{"foo": { "bar": true, "dry": false }}`
and using a `merge!` function I succeeded 

`json.merge! @foo`

gives output

`{"bar": true, "dry": false}`

as I wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you check if you have the following config?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

That should do the trick

### Update

Try this instead:

```
json.array!(@locations) do |location|
 json.id location.id
 json.name location.name
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the help!  I'm not sure what file to look in?

Comment: I believe it's `config/application.rb`

Comment: But, that would remove it for all the json feeds.  Right?  I saw this code on another q/a = my_model.to_json(:root => false).  But, I'm using jbuilder, so I don't have a json statement in my controller.

Comment: I'm hoping there is a line of code for jbuilder that would exclude the root.